# Make ShowDialog() after Show - WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

Is there any possibility to make an already shown Window in to a **Model Dialog** (Like what happens when we call `ShowDialog()`)

1. Blocking or Non Blocking, Any solution is acceptable for me, but all the Windows in the background should be disabled.
2. Hiding the window and again showing the window using ShowDialog is not possible since i have to maintain the state.

Comment: I normally will just disable the windows in the background. Just bind background windows' `IsEnabled` to a property, and set that to `true` or `false` to enable and disable.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I could get to a solution.The only issue is I change the `WindowStyle` to remove the title bar because otherwise you can still move those Windows.

```
this.Topmost = true;

foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
{
    if (window.Title != this.Title)
    {
        window.Focusable = false;
        window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        window.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
        window.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, this is close to my current solution, but Topmost will make the window Top of other applications too, also the mentioned Title bar things are still bugging me.